# Link to social media sites with logos

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to put logos for my links to like Facebook and twitter. I have the logos saved into my project images folder. I can get the link to work but all I get is a question mark instead of the picture.

This is my code for example

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="/assets/images/youtube.png"> </a></li>
```

I know there is a way to do it using the link_to and image_tag but I forgot how to do it that way. Id greatly appreciate some help using either method

This is my folder and you can see the twitter and youtube.png under my assets/images folder

[image]

Comment: can you share a link may be you are giving a wrong path

Comment: is your assets folder in the same directory as your file? don't forget to add ALT text and height / width attributes and possibly a title attribute as well - all good for code structure and SEO

Comment: @gavgrif Ya its all in the same file.

Comment: if its in the same directory - shouldnt it be... src="assets/images/youtube.png"...

Comment: Ive tried that and still no luck for some reason

Comment: maybe its in the file extension of the image stored on the server. Sometimes I have found that when saving a .png image on the server - it saved as a .PNG.....  check if you have "youtube.PNG" in the images folder on the server

Comment: Ya so I just checked and ya it is saved as .PNG

Answer (score 1):

You can use `link_to` and `image_tag` Rails helpers in the following way:

```
link_to 'your_facebook_url' do
  image_tag('youtube.png')
end
```

Make sure `your_facebook_url` is a full web address including protocol (e.g. `https://`), otherwise it will be appended to your local hostname.

Comment: I gotta be doing something wrong. Doing this the same thing, the link works perfectly fine, but still no logo. Just a tiny box with a question mark

Comment: Where is your `'youtube.png'` file located?

Comment: it is in my images file. Ill take a screen shot to show you what Im looking at from my sublime text

Comment: Can you post your `config/application.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it this way instead:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('twitter.png'), 'twitter.com' %>
```